# Conditional formatting - color cell if less than cell to the left - (inverted yield curve)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

## Example

In the following, `K2` is less than `J2`, so it's highlighted in red:

[image]

## Conditional rule

This was easy to achieve with the following conditional rule:

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to get that rule setup for the entire `K` column?

## Link to sheet

[Link to a view-only version of the document.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ipE0GSdo8H5qvcTCn-WCEp4dC5X2pA0-m5JBHoriORk/edit?usp=sharing)

## Data

The data is from the [Daily Treasury Par Yield Curve Rates](https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value_month=202204) of the *U.S. DEPARTMENT OF THE TREASURY*.

## Notes

The idea here is to have a visual indicator of when the [yield curve is inverted](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/invertedyieldcurve.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem in this way:
[image: color]

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you Daniele!